# Open to specific gvim tabs

Tags: shell-script, vim, gvim

I have a working environment that I'd like to save via a script.
-EDIT:

I don't need to save it's state, I just want my script to define it. Though saving state would work too I guess.

Currently it passes a list of file names to `gvim` via `gvim "${files[@]}" -c ":tab all"`.
Each file gets it's own tab (except that last few since there are more than 10).

What I want is an easy way to map which files end up in which tabs and how they are split. Preferably with a default of `go to new tab` for the files that don't need split?

Comment: So after realizing my question might be misinterpreted I edited and ended up realizing that saving state would work too. And googling that had better results.  
So I have my solution but it would still be nice know how to do it via a script so I'll leave this question here.